# Update gridview: Could not find control 'gvname$chkBool' in ControlParameter 'parameter'.

Tags: asp.net, aspxgridview

I'm trying to get a checkbox in a gridview to be an update parameter in a gridview. The field I want updated, author_approved_updated, is a binary field and sometimes it's null so I had to create a field in the select query string to make sure it always returns a non-null value.

But every time I try the code I get the error message about how it can't find the control in the control parameter. I checked here and many people suggested putting $ between the gridview name and the parameter name. Sadly, that doesn't work either.

Could not find control 'gvSops$chkAAU' in ControlParameter 'author_approved_updated'.

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvSops" DataSourceID="dsSops" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowSorting="true" AutoGenerateEditButton="true" DataKeyNames="sopID">
<Columns>
...
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Author Approved Updated" SortExpression="author_approved_updated">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkAAU" Checked='<%# Bind("boolAAU") %>' />
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkAAU" Checked='<%# Bind("boolAAU") %>' Enabled="false" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
...
</gridview>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsSops" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AMS %>"
SelectCommandType="Text"
SelectCommand="SELECT *, isnull(author_approved_updated, 0) as boolAAU FROM AMS_SOPs"
UpdateCommandType="Text"
updatecommand="Update AMS_SOPs SET 
    author_approved_updated = @author_approved_updated
    WHERE (sopID = @sopID)"
>
<UpdateParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="gvSops$chkAAU" PropertyName="Checked" Name="author_approved_updated" Type="Boolean" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" />
</UpdateParameters>
```

I'm not sure what else to do. Does the fact the variable in the bind function doesn't match up to the filed in the database query? Would this work better as a stored procedure instead of and update command? Does anyone know how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Testing on a similar case, I can make the update work if I set the `ControlID` to the full `name` attribute of the TextBox, as found in the HTML output. However, that name includes the row number, so the update works only for a specific row. I haven't found a way to make it work for all rows of the GridView. I personally prefer to do the databinding in code-behind, and handle the appropriate events. I have no problem finding the edit controls from there.

Comment: Thanks! I was afraid of that. I wanted to find out if I can put everything on the front page and nothing in the code-behind. Everything else worked, it's that one field that was giving me problems and it didn't seem worth the effort to event handlers for it.